# Reaction collector doesn't give an answer

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make a ban command, but the reaction collector doesn't work. I do not get an error. Here is my code (more code above, but I think that is irrelevant):

```
    const notBanYourself = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#000000")
        .setTitle("Ban")
        .setDescription("You cannot ban yourself!")
        .setFooter(message.author.username)
        .setTimestamp();

        const no_perms = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#000000")
        .setTitle("Ban")
        .setDescription("You do not have the permissions to ban that user!")
        .setFooter(message.author.username)
        .setTimestamp();

        const mention = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#000000")
        .setTitle("Ban")
        .setDescription("You have not mentioned a user, which you want to ban!")
        .setFooter(message.author.username)
        .setTimestamp();

    try {
    if (!message.mentions.users.first()) return message.channel.send(mention);
    if (member.id === message.author.id) return message.channel.send(notBanYourself);
    if (!message.member.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS") || !message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send(no_perms);
    if (message.member.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS") || message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
        const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
        const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
        const ban_dm = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#131D29")
            .setTitle("Ban")
            .setDescription("You got banned from the " + message.guild.name + " Server by \n" + message.author.username + " for " + reason + ".")
            .setTimestamp()

        memberTarget.send(ban_dm).then(() => {
            if (member) {

                const yes_no = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor("#2A333E")
                    .setTitle("Ban")
                    .setDescription(`Do you really want to ban ${member.username} from the server?`)
                    .setFooter(message.author.username)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    message.channel.send(yes_no).then((embedMsg) => {
                        embedMsg.react("✅");
                        embedMsg.react("❌");
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name == "✅";
                        const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter);
                        collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
                            memberTarget.ban({ days: 3, reason: args.slice(1).join(" ") });
                            const banned = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                            .setColor("#2A333E")
                            .setTitle("Ban")
                            .setDescription("User has been banned from the server successfully.")
                            .setFooter(message.author.username)
                            .setTimestamp();
                          message.channel.send(banned);
                        });
                    })

               
            }
        })
    }
} catch(e) {
    const errormsg = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#000000")
    .setTitle("Error")
    .setDescription("Something unknown went wrong there. It would be \n very helpful if you would report the bug \n using -feedback.")
    .setFooter(message.author.username)
    .setTimestamp();
    message.channel.send(errormsg)
    console.log(e);
}
}}
```

I hope someone can help me, would be really nice! I edited the post to give more information now. Above are only a few consts and module.exports with name, descritpion and execute.

Comment: Looks like a typo in filter `const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.id == '825036510092591174';` but if `r` is not defined it should throw an error.

Comment: Yeah i have changed it now, but it still doesnt work or throw an error

Comment: Have you tried to console.log something inside `collector.on('collect')` to see if anything is collected? Are you sure the emoji ID is correct?

Comment: I right-clicked on the emoji and then clicked "Copy ID". What should I console.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reaction.emoji.id` returns `null` for unicode emojis (like ✅, ❌, ) as only custom emojis have an `id` property.

If you want to use a unicode emoji, you can check if `reaction.emoji.name` is the emoji itself. So, for example, if you want to collect only hammer emojis (), you can use a filter like this:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '';
```

*Update:* It seems you added the reaction collector to your original message, not the one you sent as a confirmation. You need to call `createReactionCollector()` on the `embedMsg` your bot reacts to.

I've made some changes to your code to simplify it, please check below:

```js
// you don't need to repeat all these, you can add the description
// later before you send the embed
const banEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#000000')
  .setTitle('Ban')
  .setFooter(message.author.username)
  .setTimestamp();

const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first();

try {
  if (!mentionedMember)
    return message.channel.send(
      banEmbed.setDescription(
        'You have not mentioned a user, which you want to ban!',
      ),
    );

  if (mentionedMember.id === message.author.id)
    return message.channel.send(
      banEmbed.setDescription('You cannot ban yourself!'),
    );

  if (
    !message.member.permissions.has('BAN_MEMBERS') ||
    !message.member.permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR')
  )
    return message.channel.send(
      banEmbed.setDescription(
        'You do not have the permissions to ban that user!',
      ),
    );

  // add a default reason
  const reason = args.slice(1).join(' ') || 'No reason given';
  // instead of relying on the cache fetch the member (if needed)
  const memberTarget = await message.guild.members.fetch(mentionedMember.id);
  const notificationEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#131D29')
    .setTitle('Ban')
    .setDescription(
      `You got banned from the ${message.guild.name} server by ${message.author.username} for ${reason}.`,
    )
    .setTimestamp();

  memberTarget.send(notificationEmbed);

  const confirmationEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#2A333E')
    .setTitle('Ban')
    .setDescription(
      `Do you really want to ban ${memberTarget.user.username} from the server?`,
    )
    .setFooter(message.author.username)
    .setTimestamp();

  // wait for the confirmation message to be sent so you can attach 
  // a reaction collector later
  const confirmation = await message.channel.send(confirmationEmbed);
  const emojis = ['✅', '❌'];

  emojis.forEach((emoji) => confirmation.react(emoji));

  // only accept reactions from the member who wants to ban the other member
  // and if the reaction emoji is one of the emojis above
  const filter = (reaction, user) =>
    user.id === message.author.id && emojis.includes(reaction.emoji.name);

  // create the collector on the confirmation message, not the original one
  const collector = confirmation.createReactionCollector(filter, { max: 1 });

  collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    const [confirm, cancel] = emojis;

    // delete the confirmation message, as no longer needed
    confirmation.delete();

    // if the member cancelled, just send a message
    if (reaction.emoji.name === cancel) {
      const cancelEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#2A333E')
        .setTitle('Ban')
        .setDescription(
          `Cancelled! ${memberTarget} has NOT been banned from the server.`,
        )
        .setFooter(message.author.username)
        .setTimestamp();
      return message.channel.send(cancelEmbed);
    }

    // if the member confirmed, ban the user
    if (reaction.emoji.name === confirm) {
      memberTarget.ban({ days: 3, reason });
      const bannedEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#2A333E')
        .setTitle('Ban')
        .setDescription(
          `${memberTarget} has been banned from the server successfully.`,
        )
        .setFooter(message.author.username)
        .setTimestamp();
      return message.channel.send(bannedEmbed);
    }
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  const errorEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#000000')
    .setTitle('Error')
    .setDescription('Something unknown went wrong there.')
    .setFooter(message.author.username)
    .setTimestamp();
  message.channel.send(errorEmbed);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you update your post and add some more code? What is the promise this `then()` is coming from? What emoji do you use?

Comment: Oh, I see, you added the reaction collector to your original message. I've updated my answer.